# Form reset collapses labels inside the form itself

Tags: html, forms, materialize

I have been designing a website with materialize CSS.
My problem is that when I use the built-in form reset method embbeded in a reset button, the labels collapse inside the form.
This only happens if there were a value inside the form that was reset.
When I click the form it goes back to its normal state.
Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how to solve it? Or maybe another form that I can reset the form without this said behaviour?
Thanks in advance.
[Bugged form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjovq.png)
[Form before reset button being clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKGxE.png)

```
<form id="two_player">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <label for="two_player_one">Jogador 1:</label>
                <input placeholder="Apelido do jogador 1" id="two_player_one" type="text" class="validate" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Apelido do jogador 2" id="two_player_two" type="text"  class="validate" required>
                <label for="two_player_two">Jogador 2:</label>
              </div>
          </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 1ª rodada" id="two_player_one_round_one" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
                <label for="two_player_one_round_one">Rodada 1:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 1ª rodada" id="two_player_two_round_one" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
                <label for="two_player_two_round_one">Rodada 1:</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 2ª rodada" id="two_player_one_round_two" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
              <label for="two_player_one_round_two">Rodada 2:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 2ª rodada" id="two_player_two_round_two" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
              <label for="two_player_two_round_two">Rodada 2:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 3ª rodada" id="two_player_one_round_three" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
              <label for="two_player_one_round_three">Rodada 3:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 3ª rodada" id="two_player_two_round_three" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
              <label for="two_player_two_round_three">Rodada 3:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 4ª rodada" id="two_player_one_round_four" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
              <label for="two_player_one_round_four">Rodada 4:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 4ª rodada" id="two_player_two_round_four" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate" required>
              <label for="two_player_two_round_four">Rodada 4:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date1">
                <label for="date1">Qual a data da partida?</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="center-align">
          <div class="row">
              <button type="submit" class="btn grey lighten-1">Enviar</button>
              <button type="reset" class="btn grey lighten-1">Limpar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Materializecss, when an input has content or is focussed the label gets a class of 'active' added. This moves the label up, shrinks it, and colours it. When you mess with the dom via javacript, the input doesn't know about the change. To manually 'reset' the input, you need to add a class of 'active' to any input that has content (or a placeholder).

```
$("label").addClass('active');
```

In the pen below, I have two identical inputs, and in a setTimeout we remove the active class from the second label to replicate the issue you are seeing.

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/zYGWRbj

Note, in the documentation there is a function listed that does this for dynamically created inputs:

> Prefilling Text Inputs If you are having trouble with the labels
>   overlapping prefilled content, Try adding class="active" to the label.
>   You can also call the function M.updateTextFields(); to reinitialize
>   all the Materialize labels on the page if you are dynamically adding
>   inputs.

https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to run a function after click that set the timeout to update the fields.